# Using get_member in Cogs

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have two applications one main.py which is my main file and the other one is Loops.py in which I use Cogs and tasks inside them so there is a problem.I have a function to change the nickname of my bot every second to another name like this :

```
botsnick = cycle(['','','','','','','',' ',' ',' ',' '])
@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
async def change_nick():
    server = client.get_guild(771043820157534228)
    bots = server.get_member(848887911884521502)
    await bots.edit(nick=next(botsnick))
```

It is working properly in main.py but as soon as I implement this code into Loops.py and inside Cog like this :

```
class Loops(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,client):
        self.client = client
        self.change_nick.start()
        

    botsnick = cycle(['','','','','','','',' ',' ',' ',' '])
    @tasks.loop(seconds=1)
    async def change_nick(self):
        server = self.client.get_guild(771043820157534228)
        bots = server.get_member(848887911884521502)
        await bots.edit(nick=next(self.botsnick))


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Loops(client))
```

I get this error :

```
bots = server.get_member(848887911884521502)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_member'
```

but there is no error in main.py if I use this fucntion there what is wrong?

Comment: I could be completely wrong but I believe that server isn't a valid method, try using guild.get_member instead of server.get_member

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_member` gets the `Member` from cache, since the loop starts immediately, your bot's internal cache isn't ready, as a result it doesn't find anything and returns `None`

Simple fix is to use `await self.client.wait_until_ready()` in a `@yourtaskname.before_loop`

- [client.wait_until_ready()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_until_ready)